# Iterate Vertex Buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, hook

I'm trying to emulate OpenGL's GL_POINT for debugging and Reverse-Engineering OpenGL. I'm trying to iterate the Vertex-Buffer given its pointer, the Index-Buffer pointer and the stride.

So what I did:

- I hooked an application which uses OpenGL.
- I monitored the calls using gDebugger
  (application created by AMD for debugging)

To render a single model, the calls are:

```
glPushMatrix()
glViewport(4, 165, 512, 334)
glMultMatrixf({1, 0, 0, 0}
{0, 1, 0, 0}
{0, 0, 1, 0}
{26880, -741, 26368, 1})

glGenBuffersARB(1, 0x0A2B79D4)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 15)
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 17460, 0x0C85DE1C, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glGenBuffersARB(1, 0x0A2B79D4)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 16)
glBufferDataARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8946, 0x0C85DE1C, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 12, 0x31CB24C9)
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 15)
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 12, 0x00000000)
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 12, 0x00000004)
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 4473, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0x00000000)
glPopMatrix()
```

I hooked each of those calls and stored all parameters into a class and some variables.

```
typedef struct  //A struct to hold information about every buffer the application uses.
{
    GLint ID;
    GLsizei Size;
    GLboolean Reserved;
    GLboolean Bound;
    GLenum Type, Usage;
    uint32_t CheckSum;
    const GLvoid* BufferPointer;
} BufferObject;


BufferObject CurrentBuffer;  //Keep track of the currently bound buffer.
std::vector<BufferObject> ListOfBuffers;  //A list of all buffers used in the application.



//Detours the OpenGL function so that it calls this one first before calling the original one. (OpenGL call interception.)
void HookglVertexPointer(GLint size, GLenum type, GLsizei stride, const GLvoid *pointer)
{
    if ((size == 3) && (pointer != nullptr) && type == GL_FLOAT) //A model is rendering..
    {
        ModelRendering = true;
        CurrentModel.Stride = stride;
        CurrentModel.VertexPointer = pointer; //Store the pointer.
        ListOfModels.push_back(CurrentModel); //Store the model.
    }

    (*original_glVertexPointer) (size, type, stride, pointer); //Call the original function.
}

//Hook the drawing function and get each vertex being rendered.
void HookglDrawElements(GLenum mode, GLsizei count, GLenum type, const GLvoid *indices)
{
    Model* ModelPtr = &ListOfModels.back();

    if (ModelPtr != nullptr)
    {
        for (int I = 0; I < count / 3; ++I) //So for every triangle, I want to get the vertex of it and store it in my Vertices vector..
        {
            //This needs to somehow use the stride to get the right vertex.
            //Perhaps CurrentBuffer.BufferPointer instead of ModelPtr->VertexPointer.
            int X = *reinterpret_cast<const GLfloat*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ModelPtr->VertexPointer) * I);
            int Y = *reinterpret_cast<const GLfloat*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ModelPtr->VertexPointer) * I + 1);
            int Z = *reinterpret_cast<const GLfloat*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ModelPtr->VertexPointer) * I + 2);
            ModelPtr->Vertices.push_back(Vector3D(X, Y, Z));
        }
    }
    (*original_glDrawElements) (mode, count, type, indices);  //call the original function.
}
```

How can I get the vertices for each triangle if I have:

- The VBO Pointer.
- The Stride.
- The Index Pointer.

Comment: I don't see what any of that has to do with `GL_POINTS`.

Comment: GL_POINT does that when you use it with glDrawElements. If I set GL_FILL, it fills the whole model.. If I set GL_POINTS, it only displays each vertex. I want to get each of those vertices just like how the function does it when it uses GL_POINTS. I guess I'm trying to figure out how gl_drawelements works and emulate it.

Comment: I remain confused as to what this has to do with `GL_POINTS` rendering. They're using `GL_TRIANGLES`. Are you talking about the *polygon mode*, or are you talking about the primitive type you pass to a draw function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the vertices for each triangle if I have:
>
> - The VBO Pointer.
> - The Stride.
> - The Index Pointer.

You can't.

Buffer objects *do not have pointers*. `glBufferData` and `glBufferSubData` *copy* data from the given pointer into the buffer object storage. As with all OpenGL functions that don't end in the word "Pointer", [after the execution of these functions, the application is free to do whatever it wants with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697861/when-does-opengl-get-finished-with-pointers-in-functions). OpenGL *does not keep* these pointers around. And therefore, neither should you.

If you want to track the memory stored in a buffer object, you are going to have to allocate memory *yourself* and do the copy yourself. When a `glBufferData` or `glBufferSubData` call comes through, you're going to have to copy data from that pointer into your internal storage. If the user maps a buffer for writing, you're going to have to wait for the buffer to be unmapped and then copy the data back from the buffer using `glGetBufferSubData`.

It's not going to be fast.

Furthermore, you need more than a stride if you intend to render vertex data. You need the type; assuming that the user is only using `GL_FLOAT` is a pretty poor assumption (unless you want your code to be application-specific).

In any case, you are dealing with a very ill-behaved application. It seems to be using buffer objects for *some* attributes (`glColorPointer`, for example) and not using them for others (`glVertexPointer`). That's going to make your job harder.

You basically need to do what OpenGL does. For each attribute, you need to record the type, stride, normalization, and the given "pointer". But you *also* need to check whether a buffer is currently bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` (which means you need to *stop* pretending that there can only be one buffer bound at a time. You need to track what is bound to each different target).

If a buffer is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` when you call one of the "Pointer" functions, then that means that the given "pointer" isn't a pointer; it's a byte offset relative to the beginning of the buffer object. So you will need to store the "pointer" *and* the buffer object that was bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` at the time the function is called. If no buffer is bound there, then the pointer is actually a real memory pointer, which the application must keep alive so long as it attempts to render with it.

At render time, for each attribute, you either use the attribute's pointer, or use the buffer object + offset to compute where the buffer object data starts. You use that to access your copy of the buffer object data. Either way, you resolve to a pointer. You then use the type and normalization to decide how to read the data, and you use the stride to get from one vertex to the next.

Comment: Ahh I see. I have the first part completed then. I copied the data from the pointer passed to glBufferData and SubData and stored it in my vector<BufferObject> ListOfBuffers.

I didn't store what type such as GL_ARRAY_BUFFER because I only stored buffers that were GL_ARRAY_BUFFER type. I will store all now.
I don't know how to get the normalization or read the data using it but I will look it up. If its the same as in math class then I guess I divide X by length so that length of the vector is one.