# Does glUniform*fv retains passed buffer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opengl-es

What really happens when I call `glUniform2fv`?

Does it synchronously copy the passed buffer or is it just accepts the pointer and use that data later? Does it retain the buffer?

In the other words: is it safe to pass locally-created or non-retained buffers in function or it is up to me to keep that buffer alive?

I'm using OpenGL on iOS/Mac using objective-c and/or Swift, I'm afraid GC (ARC) can eat my buffer before it will be send to GPU.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does OpenGL get finished with pointers in functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697861/when-does-opengl-get-finished-with-pointers-in-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe, but the documentation is not clear on this, at least the version found at https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml

> They retain the values assigned to them by a call to glUniform until
>   the next successful link operation occurs on the program object

Comment: So they do not copy it?

Answer (score 0):

glUniform does not use any buffer (correct me if I'm wrong).
According to https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml the glUniform call modifies variables in the shader program.
In my opinion you can think the Uniform call as if it was an "=" sign in C , for example a=b;where a is the uniform in the shader program and b is a variable within your program . (Feel from to correct me if my explantion is not appropriate)