# Properly sending Uniform data to the GPU

Tags: c++, opengl

I am attempting to send Light data to my Fragment Shader via uniforms. I am having issues with the following function:

```
void glUniform3fv(GLint location, GLsizei count, const GLfloat *value);
```

Below is a function I have written, which is meant to send all the Light data (Stored as a fixed-size array in the class 'Shader') to the Fragment Shader:
(Note: The Vector3F class is my own, and I can provide its source if required.)

```
void Shader::updateLights()
{
    // this->lights[x].getPosR() returns a Vector3F reference. Same with getLightDirectionR() and getColourR().
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT1POS_U], 3, &(this->lights[0].getPosR().getXR()));
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT1LD_U], 3, &(this->lights[0].getLightDirectionR().getXR()));
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT1COLOUR_U], 3, &(this->lights[0].getColourR().getXR()));
    glUniform1f(this->uniforms[LIGHT1POW_U], this->lights[0].getPowerR());

    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT2POS_U], 3, &(this->lights[1].getPosR().getXR()));
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT2LD_U], 3, &(this->lights[1].getLightDirectionR().getXR()));
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT2COLOUR_U], 3, &(this->lights[1].getColourR().getXR()));
    glUniform1f(this->uniforms[LIGHT2POW_U], this->lights[1].getPowerR());

    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT3POS_U], 3, &(this->lights[2].getPosR().getXR()));
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT3LD_U], 3, &(this->lights[2].getLightDirectionR().getXR()));
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT3COLOUR_U], 3, &(this->lights[2].getColourR().getXR()));
    glUniform1f(this->uniforms[LIGHT3POW_U], this->lights[2].getPowerR());

    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT3POS_U], 3, &(this->lights[3].getPosR().getXR()));
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT3LD_U], 3, &(this->lights[3].getLightDirectionR().getXR()));
    glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT3COLOUR_U], 3, &(this->lights[3].getColourR().getXR()));
    glUniform1f(this->uniforms[LIGHT3POW_U], this->lights[3].getPowerR());

    // Print out all the information to ensure that data is correct.
    std::cout << "Lights Info:\n";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Shader::MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        Light* l = &(this->lights[i]);
        std::cout << "Light Id " << i << ": ";
        std::cout << "Position = [" << l->getPosR().getX() << ", " << l->getPosR().getY() << ", " << l->getPosR().getZ() << "], ";
        std::cout << "Light Direction = [" << l->getLightDirectionR().getX() << ", " << l->getLightDirectionR().getY() << ", " << l->getLightDirectionR().getZ() << "], ";
        std::cout << "Light Colour = [" << l->getColourR().getX() << ", " << l->getColourR().getY() << ", " << l->getColourR().getZ() << "], ";
        std::cout << "Light Power = " << l->getPowerR() << " Watts.\n";
    }
}
```

**However, the uniforms are empty!** I am convinced that my issue lies with my attempt for the `const GLfloat *value`. The light data is stored in the class body, so I don't think scoping is the issue.

The following block of text is printed during runtime:

```
Light Id 0: Position = [0, 15, 0], Light Direction = [0, -1, 1], Light Colour = [1, 1, 1], Light Power = 200 Watts.
Light Id 1: Position = [5, 15, 10], Light Direction = [0, -1, 1], Light Colour = [1, 1, 1], Light Power = 200 Watts
Light Id 2: Position = [10, 15, 20], Light Direction = [0, -1, 1], Light Colour = [1, 1, 1], Light Power = 200 Watts.
Light Id 3: Position = [15, 15, 30], Light Direction = [0, -1, 1], Light Colour = [1, 1, 1], Light Power = 200 Watts.
```

I've only ever seen this function being called via glm::vec3 objects, so I was not confident that I was providing enough information in the third parameter (I'm only appearing to send the X value of the Vector3F instead of XYZ). I attempted to build a list of floats in the function to ensure that all data was being sent, but the data would be lost as soon as I went out of scope, causing runtime crashing. I'd really like to avoid heap allocation in this scenario. What would be a good way to format my data so that it all is sent properly? My Fragment shader works and the Light Data is valid (So that I should see it), but the scene is pitch-black.

Comment: "*I attempted to build a list of floats in the function to ensure that all data was being sent, but the data would be lost as soon as I went out of scope, causing runtime crashing.*" [OpenGL will finish accessing this data by the time the function returns.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697861) So it is not necessary for this memory to persist beyond your call.

Comment: @NicolBolas I had no idea this was the case, thank you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> glUniform3fv(this->uniforms[LIGHT1POS_U], 3, &(this->lights[0].getPosR().getXR()));
> ```

The `count` parameter is the number of array elements in the *uniform* being written to, not the number of elements in the vector. It already knows the number of elements in the vector: that's what `3f` means in the function name.

So unless `this->uniforms[LIGHT1POS_U]` is defined as `uniform vec3 name[3];`, then this code will not work correctly. You should get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error from every single such call.

And of course, all of this assumes that whatever `getXR` returns is something that is equivalent to an array of 3 floats. Since you didn't bother to show us the code, nothing more can be said on that matter.

Comment: Ah, bad assumption on my part. Thank you. Also, getXR() is just a nonconstant function which returns the X value of the vector, which is of course wrong. I'm now putting each trio of values into its own float array and it works.