# Mutating data under reference after OpenGL call

Tags: opengl, immutability, mutable

Consider following case

```
glDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);
// buffer = 0;
...
if(buffer == 0) {
    // Should not pass but does.
}
```

of course when glDeleteBuffers is executed, buffer is set to 0, but given the delay between issuing the delete and it actually being executed, I may encounter non-zero value.

Condition above keeps passing at random, which is rather not desired.

My question is, can I assign zero to buffer without influencing queued command? I understand that when passing value, nothing bad can happen, but I found no mention in documentation how are treated references. Does OpenGL copy data from references to some immutable temporary buffer before it is "consumed"?

Tried assigning -1 hoping it would produce an error, but due to random behavior of the problem, I really do not want to rely on "did not happen, will not happen".

Comment: Why do you think `glDeleteBuffers` changes the value of buffer? The second parameter is a `const GLuint*` which means it cannot be modified by the function.

Comment: Now that is rather strange, as the condition does not always pass.

Comment: Undefined behavior because you are using `buffer` after you have told GL to delete it.

Comment: I'm using it, yes, but not for OpenGL calls.

Comment: True. Do you get random behavior with a debug build? Without knowledge of the lines between the '...' difficult to say what state `buffer` is in when you query it. The code you posted should not produce UB, so if it is that line, something else is mutating `buffer` without your knowledge, but its not `glDeleteBuffers`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> of course when glDeleteBuffers is executed, buffer is set to 0

No, it is not. None of the `glDelete*` functions will modify the buffer name you provide.

> but given the delay between issuing the delete and it actually being executed, I may encounter non-zero value.

Even if the `glDelete*` functions did overwrite the array you passed, they would do so *immediately*, just like [almost every other OpenGL function that writes to memory you provide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15697861/734069).

> My question is, can I assign zero to buffer without influencing queued command?

`buffer` is just an integer; you can set it to whatever you like. OpenGL will keep doing what it is doing.

When you delete an OpenGL object, it will only actually be deleted [after the object stops being attached to other objects and after the GPU gets done with whatever processes acted on it](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Deletion_orphaning). But whether or not you throw away your reference to that object isn't related to that.

Answer (score 0):

`glDeleteBuffers` does never change the value of the passed variable. Actually, the second parameter is a `const GLuint*` which means it is constant and cannot be modified.

About passing -1: Besides the fact that buffer references are *unsigned* integers, the [reference](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glDeleteBuffers.xhtml) states:

> glDeleteBuffers silently ignores 0's and names that do not correspond to existing buffer objects

In general and for (almost) all OpenGL call: You can assign whatever you want to any variable you passed to OpenGL. When a OpenGL call returns it is guaranteed that it has finished processing the client side memory (with a few exceptions, read [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Synchronization) for more details).

Comment: Oh, my bad, did read "GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if n is negative." and automatically assumed it is for buffer index, not buffer count.