# Memory data flow for uniform variables?

Tags: opengl

When a texture (2D) is supplied to a shader as a 'uniform' input, it is first uploaded to OpenGL using glTexImage2D() and then using glUniform1i() it is associated to shader uniform.

eg code :

**Texture data**

`glTexImage2D()`: is used to transfer texture data to the server side.

`glGetUniformLocation()`: is used to access shader uniform handle.

`glUniform1i()`: associates the data pointed by texture unit to the shader 'uniform' input.

but when we pass matrix (eg matrix4x4) to a shader as a 'uniform' input, when don't use any specific function to upload it to OpenGL. We just used glUniform..() to associate the data with the shader input which we also used in the case of associating texture data that is already present in OpenGL memory.

**Matrix data**

`glGetUniformLocation()`: to access shader uniform handle

`glUniformMatrix4fv()`: to associate matrix data to the shader uniform input.

**Where does the matrix data live in each step in the process of passing it to a shader as a uniform input?**

- Does matrix data always live on client side/ CPU accessible memory and fetched every frame by server side?
- If it is uploaded to OpenGL:

  - which step/function call uploads the data?
  - where does the data live in OpenGL memory?
  - how its memory location is pointed?

Comment: The values of the uniform variables "life" in the data store of the default uniform block on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

> associates the data pointed by texture unit to the shader 'uniform' input.

No, this sets the "value" of the uniform variable (`uniform`s are not "inputs") to be the texture unit index where the sampler can find the texture that this uniform represents. The value is just a value; it is no different from the way you set the value of *any* uniform variable.

It's just that in GLSL, you don't access the "value" of the sampler uniform variable; you use texture accessing functions on it instead.

If you change the texture bound to that texture unit before you render with the shader, then the shader will see the new texture. It is not directly associated with any texture; the shader is only associated with a texture unit index.

> Where does the matrix data live in each step in the process of passing it to a shader as a uniform input?

There's only one step in the "process" of passing uniform values to shaders. You make a `glUniform*` call, and the "process" is complete; the particular uniform now has that particular value.

This is no different from setting pretty much any state in OpenGL. If you make a `glTexParameter` call, that performs the "process" of setting the state value you pass into the proper place in the OpenGL texture object.

> Does matrix data always live on client side/ CPU accessible memory and fetched every frame by server side?

It lives wherever the implementation chooses to put it. However, [all OpenGL functions are finished with the pointers you pass them by the time they return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15697861/734069). So you don't have to worry about *your* CPU memory.

Comment: "It lives wherever the implementation chooses to put it. However, all OpenGL functions are finished with the pointers you pass them by the time they return." 
- if implementation decides to store/keep data on client side, can an OpenGL pointer point to CPU memory location?

Comment: @user2259784: What is "an OpenGL pointer"? What the implementation does is its own business. It can have pointers to CPU memory and GPU memory; just not to memory owned by *you*.