# OpenGL 1.1: Can memory be freed after calling glNormalPointer()?

Tags: opengl, segmentation-fault

I have some old code that uses OpenGL 1.1 that is mysteriously segfaulting. One place where I might be going wrong is that I `free()` an array after providing it to [`glNormalPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormalPointer.xml). Is that permitted, or does OpenGL require the memory at that pointer to stick around? I had been assuming that the data was copied.

```
double vertices[] = { ... };
double *normals = (double *)malloc(sizeof(vertices));

CalcNormals(vertices, normals, num_vertices);  // Calculate the normal vectors.

GLuint my_display_list = glGenLists(1);
glNewList(my_display_list, GL_COMPILE);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, vertices);
glNormalPointer(GL_DOUBLE, 0, normals);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, num_vertices);
glEndList();

free(normals); // Is this permitted?

// ...

glCallList(winglist);
```

EDIT 1: I noticed a few references that say that glNormalPointer and other "client state commands" cannot be included in a display list. I guess in this case, inclusion of `glVertexPointer` and `glNormalPointer` between `glNewList` and `glEndList` probably does no harm, but I might as well move them up, to occur before `glNewList`. It's the call to `glDrawArrays` that's really being recorded in the display list, right?

EDIT 2: I tried calling `memset(normals, 0, sizeof(vertices))` to forcefully clear the normals buffer before freeing it, to make a use-after-free situation more obvious. Because the scene still draws properly, I conclude that the normals buffer that I allocate is not being used after the call to `glDrawArrays`.

Comment: Have you ever tried a debugger to see what the faulty access even is?

Comment: @derhass - The trouble is that it works fine on my machine, but I have reports that it segfaults for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I noticed a few references that say that glNormalPointer and other "client state commands" cannot be included in a display list.

No, it says that they *aren't* included in the display list. Which is true; they aren't.

But their *effects* can be.

The `gl*Pointer` commands [retain the pointer well after their the command executes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15697862/734069). That is, the pointer isn't used yet. It only gets read from when you invoke a rendering command using that pointer as client state.

The behavior of `glDraw*` calls with client-side vertex arrays is defined in terms of a sequence of calls to `glArrayElement` within a `glBegin/End` pair, which itself is defined in terms of a series of call to `glVertex/Normal/etc`, using values read from the vertex arrays. Display lists record those `glVertex/etc` calls into the display list itself. Thus, while recording to a display list, when you render with client-side vertex arrays you will record the *contents* of the arrays into the display list.

You can free the client memory only if you don't try to read from it again.